# What is the minimum number of ordered pairs

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

What is the minimum number of ordered pairs of non-negative numbers that should be chosen to ensure that there are two pairs (a,b) and (c,d) in the chosen set such that $$a \equiv c \mod \;3 \;and \;b \equiv d \mod \;5$$

1. 4
2. 6
3. 16
4. 24

---

Somewhere it explained as :

order pair for (a,b) are

```
(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) (0,4)
(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) (1,4)
(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3) (2,4)
```

take any other combination for (c,d) that ll surely match with one of the above 15 combination.(Pigeon Hole principle)
total 15+1 = 16 combination

> Can you explain in formal way please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every non-negative integer is congruent to exactly one of $0,1$, and $2$ modulo $3$, and every non-negative integer is congruent to exactly one of $0,1,2,3$, and $4$ modulo $5$. Thus, there are $3$ congruence classes modulo $3$, and $5$ congruence classes modulo $5$.

Now consider an ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ of non-negative integers: $a$ can be congruent to any one of $0,1$, and $2$ modulo $3$, and, independently of that, $b$ can be congruent to any one of $0,1,2,3$, and $4$ modulo $5$. In effect the pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ uses $a$ to select one item from the $3$-element ‘menu’ $0,1,2$ of congruence classes modulo $3$, and $b$ to select one item from the $5$-element ‘menu’ $0,1,2,3,4$ of congruence classes modulo $5$.

Each of the $3$ possible congruence classes for $a$ can be paired with any of the $5$ possible congruence classes for $b$, so there are $3\cdot 5=15$ possible ordered pairs of congruence classes – $15$ ways to select one item from each ‘menu’. Those $15$ possibilities are listed in your table: no matter what non-negative integers $a$ and $b$ are, reducing $a$ modulo $3$ and $b$ modulo $5$ will yield exactly one of the entries in that table. For instance, $\langle 22,108\rangle$ reduces to $\langle 1,3\rangle$, because $22\equiv1\pmod3$, and $108\equiv3\pmod5$.

If you take any two entries in your table, either they’re in different rows, in which case their first components are not congruent modulo $3$, or they’re in different columns, in which case their second components are not congruent modulo $5$. If you have $16$ (or more) ordered pairs, however, at least two of them, say $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle c,d\rangle$ must reduce to the same entry in that table, say the entry $\langle i,j\rangle$. But then

$$a\equiv i\equiv c\pmod3$$

and

$$b\equiv j\equiv d\pmod5\;,$$

so $a\equiv c\pmod3$ and $b\equiv d\pmod5$, as desired.

Comment: @Mithlesh: You're very welcome.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott . This is the *correct* explanation. I was wondering why are they taking only those 15 pairs for <a,b> why not <1001,1003> ,   You cleared my doubt. It is selecting one element from each *class* of ordered pairs. Thanks